# Excel VBA throwing a cache issue error 1004 with Workbooks.Open?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a vba code by opening a file and running a series of codes using a .xlsm file. I'm opening an excel file using the code below:

```
Dim sPath As String, sName As String

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
sName = Dir(sPath & "*cash*.xls?")

If sName <> "" Then
    With Workbooks.Open(sName)
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Cash & CC Sales"
    End With
End If
```

After running the series of codes, I save the file using SaveAs - code below:

```
Dim sPath4 As String, datePath4 As String

datePath4 = Replace(Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("N2").Value, "/", "-")

sPath4 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Dashboard " & datePath4 & ".xls"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath4, FileFormat:=xlNormal

End Sub
```

This works for the first time. When I run the code again after a while after re-opening the .xlsm file, it throws me an error 1004 saying it cannot find the file "Cash Listing.xls", however, I've never actually defined it as that file name in the vba code and instead used "cash*.xls?", which leads me to believe there's some sort of cache issue? that's making it try and open an older file. Also, oddly, "Cash Listing.xls" in fact, does exist.

Any ideas why and how this error would come about and how to circumvent this bug? The code works and runs for the first time, after which, it throws me the error and the only way I can resolve it is to create a new .xlsm file and copy the code there and run it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your provided code I have managed to re-create the error locally. It seems that, despite the line `sName = Dir(sPath & "*cash*.xls?")`, your `sName`-string still only contains the filename (and not the path), in your case: `Cash Listing.xls`. If I'm reading the docs correctly, this is how the `Dir`-function is to behave, as it *Returns a String representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute* [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If you change your code to include sPath in the Workbooks.Open line, this should solve the problem. (at least it does so on my local reproduction):

```
Dim sPath As String, sName As String

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
sName = Dir(sPath & "*cash*.xls?")

If sName <> "" Then
    With Workbooks.Open(sPath & sName)
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Cash & CC Sales"
    End With
End If
```

It is not clear to me why the `Workbooks.Open(sName)` works right after creating the xlsm-file, but if the above solution solves your problem then hopefully that's good enough :)

Comment: Thanks. It's weird why it works the first time and why it says "Cash Listing.xls" was not found the second time when the code doesn't even define that name, but your fix works - so far so good.